Can I use a boolean operation on 2D curves?
It shows here but not in blender 4.2.2. I put the switch in to flick between the both. TIA
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-2d-boolean-geometry-nodes/20349/14



Please sepcify "work" - what would "working" look like in your opinion? First of all, your Mesh Boolean node will not generate any output because - as the name suggests - it expects meshes as input, not curves. So to use it you would have to plug Curve to Mesh after each curve primitive. Okay, but this could be simplified beforehand by a Join Geometry. But if you plug the joined curves into a Curve to Mesh node and then into a Mesh Boolean node, the result will be exactly the same as if you did not use a Mesh Boolean at all - so the question remains, what means "working" for you?

Working means everything in the circle would be gone since the 'Union' is selected. I added what you said to do.

The Mesh Boolean as well as the Boolean modifier need manifold geometry to work properly, so ideally the curves should be filled and even have a thickness. Although I think the Mesh Boolean in Geometry Nodes is more "forgiving" and might even work with flat planes. But I'm not on a PC right now to test it. Maybe you could also try to switch the solver from Exact to Float.

Boolean Mesh is only reliable with manifold meshes, so you need to convert your curves to manifold meshes by giving them thickness:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Example: the starting geometry you provided.
Fill Curves: according to my tests separating curves into instances is much faster than using "Group ID" of "Fill Curve" node. And separation is needed, because otherwise overlapping curves alternate fill/no fill.
Solidify: extruding in geonodes doesn't leave behind the base, so you need to merge with the copy of the base.
Manifold Boolean: because of previous step, now boolean should work reliably.
Delete Top: after boolean the extruded part is no longer needed.
Delete Internal Edges: to my understanding you're interested in just the silhouette. Because I deleted the top, I created discontinuity ("boundary", hanging faces) on that silhouette.

And finally convert back to curve if that's what you need.

Imgur mirror


But how can I then sweep that on a circle?

@PaulMoore please ask a new question if you have additional requests
